# csv skipping appending data skips rows

Tags: python, csv

I have python code for appending data to the same csv, but when I append the data, it skips rows, and starts from row 15, instead from row 4

```
import csv

with open('csvtask.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    ls = []
    for line in csv_reader:
        if len(line['Values'])!= 0:
            ls.append(int(line['Values']))

new_ls = ['','','']
for i in range(len(ls)-1):
    new_ls.append(ls[i+1]-ls[i])

print(new_ls)

with open('csvtask.csv','a',newline='') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
    for i in new_ls:
        csv_writer.writerow(('','','','',i))
    new_file.close()
```

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: You are opening the output file in ‘a’ (append) so when you write to it the data is appended on the end - that’s why you get three blank rows which correspond to the three empty rows that you initialise new_ls to.

Comment: @barny Yes, I understand that, but how to write data from row 4, and not row 15

Comment: If you want the output file to have the existing data with more columns you’ll have to open the output file in ‘w’ and then write all the data out including the columns from the data you read. At the moment you discard this data so you’ll have to change the reading code to keep it as first two columns, then on each of those rows add your new columns, then write all the modified rows out using a DictWriter.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? (So we don't have to guess,)

Comment: @martineau I want data in column 5, start from row 4, not 15

Answer (score 1):

It's not really feasible to update a file at the same time you're reading it, so a common workaround it to create a new file. The following does that while preserving the fieldnames in the origin file. The new column will be named `Diff`.

Since there's no previous value to use to calculate a difference for the first row, the rows of the files are processed using the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function which provides a value each time it's called which provides the index of the item in the sequence as well as the item itself as the object is iterated. You can use the index to know whether the current row is the first one or not and handle in a special way.

```
import csv

# Read csv file and calculate values of new column.
with open('csvtask.csv', 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames  # Save for later.
    diffs = []
    prev_value = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        row['Values'] = int(row['Values']) if row['Values'] else 0
        diff = row['Values'] - prev_value if i > 0 else ''
        prev_value = row['Values']
        diffs.append(diff)

# Read file again and write an updated file with the column added to it.
fieldnames.append('Diff')  # Name of new field.
with open('csvtask.csv', 'r', newline='') as inp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp)
    with open('csvtask_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as outp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for i, row in enumerate(reader):
            row.update({'Diff': diffs[i]})  # Add new column.
            writer.writerow(row)

print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DictWriter function like this:-

```
header = ["data", "values"]
writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)
data = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: csv_writer.writerow(('','','','',i)) this is because I want to write data in row 5, and new_ls = ['','',''] is to leave first 3 rows empty

Comment: I just edited my asnwer sorry for not including how to write to row 4 completely forgot

Comment: I am not sure, how to insert this in my code ?

Comment: actually you can use the dictwriter function, i again edited my answer. Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-data-from-a-python-list-to-csv-row-wise/